# Reduce array of results in to array of objects with sums and user id

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I am attempting to take an array of results and reduce them into a single array.

The data is:

```
const data = [
    { profileid: '1', points: 25, winner: true },
    { profileid: '2', points: 15, winner: false },
    { profileid: '3', points: 18, winner: false },
    { profileid: '1', points: 15, winner: true },
    { profileid: '2', points: 18, winner: false },
    { profileid: '3', points: 25, winner: false },
]
```

I am attempting to sum up all points by userid (I have achieved this) and also sum up the amount of times `winner === true` in each object

**Expected Results**

```
[
    { profileid: '1', points: 40, wins: 1 },
    { profileid: '2', points: 33, wins: 0 },
    { profileid: '3', points: 43, wins: 1 },
]
```

Currently I am unable to talley the sum of "true" results in each object. Additionally I am returning an object instead of an array.

**Snippet**

```js
const data = [
    { profileid: '1', points: 25, winner: true },
    { profileid: '2', points: 15, winner: false },
    { profileid: '3', points: 18, winner: false },
    { profileid: '1', points: 15, winner: false },
    { profileid: '2', points: 18, winner: false },
    { profileid: '3', points: 25, winner: true },
]

const result = data.reduce((acc, cur) => ({
            ...acc,
            [cur.profileid]: {
                profileid: cur.profileid,
                points: cur.points + (acc[cur.profileid] ? acc[cur.profileid].points : 0),
                wins: cur.winner
                    ? acc[cur.profile]
                        ? acc[cur.profile].wins + 1
                        : 0
                    : acc[cur.profile]
                    ? acc[cur.profile].wins
                    : 0,
            },
        }),
        []
    )
    
console.log(result)
```

Comment: So whats the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript group by array field and reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67581324/javascript-group-by-array-field-and-reduce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying the same logic for the `points` can give something like:

```js
wins: cur.winner ? ((acc[cur.profileid]?.wins || 0) + 1) : (acc[cur.profileid]?.wins || 0),
```

Were we start by checking if the current `winner` is `true`

- If so, add `1` (`|| 0`) for the first time where `wins` doesn't exist
- If not, just use `acc[cur.profileid]?.wins` (also a fallback if the first time is `false`)

```js
const data = [
    { profileid: '1', points: 25, winner: true },
    { profileid: '2', points: 15, winner: false },
    { profileid: '3', points: 18, winner: false },
    { profileid: '1', points: 15, winner: false },
    { profileid: '2', points: 18, winner: false },
    { profileid: '3', points: 25, winner: true },
]

const result = data.reduce((acc, cur) => ({
        ...acc,
        [cur.profileid]: {
            wins: cur.winner ? ((acc[cur.profileid]?.wins || 0) + 1) : (acc[cur.profileid]?.wins || 0),
            profileid: cur.profileid,
            points: cur.points + (acc[cur.profileid] ? acc[cur.profileid].points : 0),
        },
    }),
    []
)
    
console.log(result)
```

---

That said, I'd personally prefer a simple `for` and a single `if` to get a more readable code:

Please consider this example:

- Create empty `result` obj
- Loop over each obj in the `data` array
- Create empty obj in `data` if needed
- Bump the `points` and `wins` values

```js
const data = [
    { profileid: '1', points: 25, winner: true },
    { profileid: '2', points: 15, winner: false },
    { profileid: '3', points: 18, winner: false },
    { profileid: '1', points: 15, winner: false },
    { profileid: '2', points: 18, winner: false },
    { profileid: '3', points: 25, winner: true },
];
const result = {};

for (let i in data) {
  
    // Create current profileId object
    if (!result[data[i].profileid]) {
        result[data[i].profileid] = {
            wins: 0,
            points: 0,
            profileid: +data[i].profileid
        };
    }

    // Bump points/wins values
    result[data[i].profileid].points += data[i].points;
    result[data[i].profileid].wins += +data[i].winner;
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sum the `wins` the same way as you sum the `points`:

```js
const data = [
    { profileid: '1', points: 25, winner: true },
    { profileid: '2', points: 15, winner: false },
    { profileid: '3', points: 18, winner: false },
    { profileid: '1', points: 15, winner: true },
    { profileid: '2', points: 18, winner: false },
    { profileid: '3', points: 25, winner: true },
]

const result = data.reduce((acc, cur) => ({
            ...acc,
            [cur.profileid]: {
                profileid: cur.profileid,
                points: cur.points + (acc[cur.profileid] ? acc[cur.profileid].points : 0),
                wins: cur.winner + (acc[cur.profileid] ? acc[cur.profileid].wins : 0)
            },
        }),
        []
    )
    
console.log(result)
```

You can also simplify `wins` like this: 
`wins: !!(acc[cur.profileid]?.wins) + cur.winner`

In case `acc[cur.profileid]?.wins` returns `undefined`, 
 you can convert it to a **Boolean** by `!!` or `Boolean()` to avoid getting `NaN`

[Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) 
[Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)